# rails send_data with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using ROR

example, from my "index" page user clicks on "view report". this calls method "run" via "ajax"

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "xyz", action: "run"}, method: "post", remote: true) do |f| %>
```

since it was called from "index" page. I am populating report summary at the bottom of the "index" page

- so far so good

But here is the problem. In addition to populating the summary I also have to send a full report and that's a excel file.

```
def run
    begin
        # populating summary here
        csv(data["report"], params)
    rescue Exception => e
        puts e.inspect
        flash[:error] = "some error"
        redirect_to action: "help" and return
    end
end

def csv(report, params)
    send_data(report,
    type:         'text/csv',
    filename:      "name.csv",
    disposition:  'attachment')
end
```

Currently I have to comment csv(data["report"], params) and use ajax (remote: true) to have my summary on the page. Or take the ajax out and uncomment the csv call to pop up the excel.

Is it possible to do both with ajax?